# Passing a 2D array from one Perl script to another

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script called `master.pl`. I have a 2D array in that called `@inputarray`.

I need to pass the 2D array values from `master.pl` to another program called `child.pl` and access the data in the `child.pl`.

I have tried a lot but I'm not able to dereference the array in `child.pl`.

Can you please help me?

**master.pl**

```
system "start perl child.pl $appl $count @inputarray";
```

**child.pl**

```
($appl, $count, @inputarray) = @ARGV;

for (my $k = 0; $k < $count + 1; $k++) {
    for (my $m = 0; $m < 6; $m++) {
        print "$inputarray[$k][$m] ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Add a snippet with the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Serialize it with `Data::Dumper` or `Storable`

Comment: ...or YAML. And I'm sure there are plenty of other options on CPAN...

Comment: Why not just `@ARGV = ($appl, $count, @inputarray); do 'child.pl';`? If you're not going to do it properly, why not do it not properly properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Method 1:***

Have a look at the standard module [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper), it's ideal for what you want.

Save your data structure in a temporary file using Data::Dumper and then read it in your second script.

***Method 2:***

Using [Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) to store array in first script and retrieve it from other.

**Edit (after you provided your code):**

See you can access the array like this

**master.pl**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
my @inputarray = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]);
store (\@inputarray, "/home/chankey/child.$$") or die "could not store";
system("perl", "child.pl", $$) == 0 or die "error";
```

**child.pl**

```
#/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
use Data::Dumper;
my $parentpid = shift;
my $ref = retrieve("/home/chankey/child.$parentpid") or die "coudn't retrieve";
print Dumper $ref;
print $$ref[0][0]; #prints 1
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ],
          [
            7,
            8,
            9
          ]
        ]; #from Dumper
  1 #from print $$ref[0][0]
```

As you can see from dump, you've received the `@inputarray` in `$ref`. Now use it the way you want.

Comment: is there any way without creating a text file.because i was given a constraint that I should not use any temporary text files.

Comment: I am able to get the address into the child file but just not able to retrieve the values from the adresses. Even if i print any value i m able to print the address and not the value at that location.

Comment: Check the edited answer, I've included the code and also tested it. It's working fine. You can just add a loop to print values.

Comment: Yeah dude.thanks a lot :).But it is creating some temporary files.I dont want those temp files to be created

Answer (score 1):

Check [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) for any kind of perl data serialization/deserialization.

For passing data between processes on POSIX systems I use [named pipes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Named-Pipes), for better compatibility with Windows you could use temporary files, using File::Temp.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous pipe, which works in the same way on UNIX and Windows (I assume you are using Windows because of the `start`.
Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $appl = 'orange';
my @inputarray = ([0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]);
```

We don't need `$count`, you can get the number of elements in the array using scalar context, or the highest index number using `$#inputarray`;

I have omitted the `start` because it makes it difficult to debug (the console window closes after the run).

```
my $cmd = 'perl child.pl';
open(my $pipe, '|-', $cmd) or 
    die "Unable to execte $cmd; $!";
```

Using Data::Dumper we can add `eval` statements and reduce whitespace generation:

```
use Data::Dumper;

local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;

my $dat = Data::Dumper->new([\$appl,\@inputarray],
                            [qw($appl $inputarray)]);

print $pipe $dat->Dump();
close ($pipe);
```

Now for the child, which reads the pipe (input stream):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($inp) = <STDIN>;

my ($appl, $inputarray);
eval "$inp";
print "appl = $$appl\n";
```

Use of `eval` is usually frowned upon, and it can give a security hole, so use with care.  I think it is justifed here.

Your loops are a tad complex, and smell of C.  These are rather more Perlish:

```
for my $ref (@$inputarray) {
    for my $ele (@$ref) {
        print "$ele "
    }
    print "\n"
}
```

YAML is safer, because it does not require the `eval`, but needs to be installed.

Comment: I am not too much into perl. Should i create a pipe before i Write it to the pipe using the command "print $pipe $dat->Dump()"

Comment: I think pipe should have both pipe read and pipe write for reading from and writing to a pipe. Should I do that explicitly or is it just I have to declare it as a file handle and use it?

Comment: @BharadwajT: with anonymous pipes, the `open` creates the new pipe and the new process (client.pl), then the current process writes to the pipe file handle.  In client.pl we just read STDIN, and that is already connected to the read side of the pipe.  Try the code example, it is complete, (tested on Windows 7) to get the idea.